# Modifying jupyter notebook in init code

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to modify the contents of a notebook in the notebook `startup` code? I want to run some init code and add "header" cells to every notebook on a machine based on the code, for instance grab the hash of the current head from a local git repo, or pull a file from S3 to the local file system.

I can put a bunch of scripts, either `.py` or `.ipy` in the `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/` directory and I'd like to modify the notebook that is currently being opened using those scripts (or some other scripts if that's possible).

According to the [docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files) the shell has already been setup when those scripts run, so I'm thinking there should be some way of accessing, at a minimum, the local path of the notebook that was opened. I could then use `nbformat` ([github](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat)) to modify the contents.

Alternatively I could use `NotebookApp` or `ContentsManager` to possibly modify the running notebook, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that and the notebook docs are pretty light on the actual API for those classes. This might not be possible as the init code is executed in the kernel, which does not know what the front end is, it could be the case that the kernel is connected to a `console` not to a `notebook` or to both a `notebook` and a `console`.

So

1. can I access the filename of the current notebook in a startup script?
2. should I rather be looking to modify the notebook cells through `NotebookApp`, `FileContentsManager` or some other internal class?

---

related

- There is an open issue for template files https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/332 -- this is not what I'm looking for, the template files are static, I need to modify the notebook based on the result of a computation